# url character encoding in an angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Our app requires an email be sent to a formatted address for tracking purposes the format required to be sent to the mail client is like this:

```
<a href="mailto\:David Contact<{contactId=2} {userId=2} {pitchingInitiativeId=9}@mail.com>" target="_blank">
```

In my template I format the href string like this...

```
mailto:{{contact.name}}<{contactId={{contact.contactId}}} {userId={{userId}}} {pitchingInitiativeId={{pitchingInitiativeId}}}@propelmymail.com>
```

This results in a mailto link that is formatted like this:

```
mailto:Reporter%3C%7BcontactId=1%7D%20%7BuserId=7%7D%20%7BpitchingInitiativeId=21%7D@propelmymail.com%3E
```

Which is obviously not correct. How do I fix this so a mailto link is formatted correctly? I believe that there is a general understanding that special characters are dangerous in URLS, but in this case it's the requirement. I guess I have just never learned how to escape them or mark them as safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Which Characters Are Allowed in URLs?**
>
> Not all special characters will cause an issue in your URLs. There are
> many safe characters. Other non-safe characters risk poor readability,
> breaking some browsers and causing issues for crawlers.
>
> **Safe characters**
> **Standard characters:**
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h I j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y
> z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> **Special characters:**
>
> $ – _ . + ! * ‘ ( ) ,

From: https://www.abramillar.com/2018/01/15/special-characters-short-words-urls/

Also take a look at -
[Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

---

It is per design that you shouldn't be allowed to parse in other characters.

What I would suggest is to put in whatever you need to track, into the title or email body.